# Running the program in Eclipse works fine, but the jar doesn't

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar

I'm creating an application that should work in both Windows and OSX systems. When I finished developing and testing it on OSX, I finally exported to a Runnable Jar File, and it worked just fine. But when I got it to run in another machine (Windows) it threw an Exception. I'm not 100% sure of what's the problem, but I believe it's using some of Eclipse's libs or something, because if I get the project to run from the Eclipse in the Windows machine, it works too.

I tried to work my way around the manifest.mf trying to generate a Runnable Jar by myself, but I haven't worked so far.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(
    JarRsrcLoader.java:58)

Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
    javax.imageio.spi.ImageInputStreamSpi: 
        Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.stream.ChannelImageInputStreamSpi 
            could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(
            Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at javaxt.io.Image.<clinit>(Image.java:50)
        at Image.<init>(Image.java:40)
        at ImageFolder.<init>(ImageFolder.java:108)
        at GeotagImages.main(GeotagImages.java:49)
        ... 5 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName == null!
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIOServiceProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.ImageInputStreamSpi.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.stream.ChannelImageInputStreamSpi.<init>(
            ChannelImageInputStreamSpi.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(
            Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
```

This is what the Runnable JAR export generated:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ poi-3.12.jar commons-validator-1.4.1.jar javaxt-co
 re.jar gson-2.3.1.jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar ojdbc6.jar 
 commons-net-3.3.jar commons-imaging-1.0.jar imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar comm
 ons-io-2.4.jar jai_imageio-1.1.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: br.com.inforsec.GeotagImages.GeotagImages
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

And then I tried to mix with some stuff that I found of forums, but I didn't quite understand it:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ poi-3.12.jar commons-validator-1.4.1.jar javaxt-co
 re.jar gson-2.3.1.jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar ojdbc6.jar 
 commons-net-3.3.jar commons-imaging-1.0.jar imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar comm
 ons-io-2.4.jar jai_imageio-1.1.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: br.com.inforsec.GeotagImages.GeotagImages
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
Name: br/com/inforsec/GeotagImages/
Specification-Title: Georeference Tag Images
Specification-Version: 0.7
Specification-Vendor: Inforsec Ltda.
Implementation-Title: br.com.inforsec.GeotagImages 
Implementation-Version: build07
Implementation-Vendor: Inforsec Ltda.
```

Well, it didn't work and I'm kinda lost on how to solve it.

Here's a snippet on where I'm trying to read the images:

```
public class Image {
    private String path;
    private File file;

    public Image(String path){

        GeotagImages.LOG.println("Image: Starting");

        this.path = path;
        File imageFile = new File(path);
        GeotagImages.LOG.println("Image: path = " + path);
        javaxt.io.Image image = new javaxt.io.Image(imageFile);
        this.file = new File(path);
    . . .
```

The exception is throw at the line 41:

```
javaxt.io.Image image = new javaxt.io.Image(imageFile);
```

Comment: From memory, `jai_imageio-1.1.jar` should be in the `ext` directory of your JRE (or at least it that's how it worked for me).  You might also want to provide a snippet of the code based on how you are reading the images